# Finding the average number

Tags: python

For the task I need the average score of each person so if Dan scored 5 in one line and 7 in another he would then be displayed as having an average of 6.the average is what i need ordered and displayed. 
so I have to sort the into the highest average scores that people have gained, to the lowest average and display the sorted version of it in python. one of the file I have to sort looks like this.

Bob:0
Bob:1
Jane:9
Drake:8
Dan:4
Josh:1
Dan:5

How can i do this on python?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your coding efforts, errors and desired output

Comment: I was given it to do and it counts toward my final grade at school. My teacher didn't teach me how to do it or actually teach us anything to do with said task. no one in my class knows how to do it and I've spent a lot of time googleing, reading through coding walkthroughs and still don't have any idea so i asked the question. sorry if it was so out of the question.

Comment: Please google "File reading python + Stackoverflow" you will number of useful links.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: This is a duplicate, I have just answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350746/sorting-lines-by-the-second-word-on-each-line-of-text-file-than-displaying-it/32351239#32351239)

Comment: no Its not that is sorting highest to lowest. the main problem here is getting the average score of each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open('in.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for x in data:
    x = x.strip()
    if not x:
        continue
    name = x.split(':')[0].strip()
    score = int(x.split(':')[-1].split('/')[0].strip())
    if name not in d:
        d[name] = {}
        d[name]['score'] = 0
        d[name]['count'] = 0
    d[name]['count'] += 1
    d[name]['score'] = (d[name]['score'] + score) / float(d[name]['count'])

ds = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: d[k]['score'], reverse=True)

for x in ds:
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(x, d[x]['score']))
```

Comment: there is a small problem and im not sure what it means.                                                                                                ds = sorted(d.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: d[k]['score'], reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Comment: it means the sample input you provided did not accurately depict what your actual input file looks like

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be its the name,colon,space,score,space,/10 In each line

Comment: upload your input file somewhere and post the link

Comment: it's this basic form (it's supposed to work on a couple files which have different names, scores and amount of people. it all still looks like this name,colon,space,score,space,/10 In each line)                                                                                          Janet: 8 /10  next line
Chris: 10 /10   next line
Janet: 4 /10   next line 
Chris: 1 /10  next line
Trevor: 2 /10  next line
Chris: 7 /10  next line
Trevor: 3 /10  next line
put in a notepad

Comment: i tested it again and it worked...please tell me you changed "in.txt" in the code to the name of your input file...

Comment: i did change the in.txt. I test it again ill message you the result. thanks

Comment: No it didn't work. Is there any thing else i need to change other than the in.txt part

Comment: is the script in the same directory as your input file?

Comment: yes it is. All in the same folder right besides each other.

Comment: what python version are you running?

Comment: I love. you. thanks so much for this. you're a saint It works perfectly